# Unable to load 'nviz' through GRASS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, 3d, sextante, nviz

I am using QGIS 2.0.1-Dufouron on Windows 7. When I try to load nviz via GRASS, I get the message "Module nviz not found". Weirdly enough, I can load it via the toolbox and be able to 'run' it (it reaches 100%). But afterwards, nothing happens.

**Problem:** I merely want to rotate and play around with the view points of layers. This is all for aesthetic purposes, don't want to do anything technical (not yet anyway).

I have read posts on people suggesting to install the plugin SEXTANTE which may solve the issue, however it doesn't show up on my list of plugins (maybe I don't have the correct URL?). I am considering trying ArcMap if I have to but would rather do it in QGIS.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: SEXTANTE in QGIS is now called processing and is integrated into QGIS since version 2.0. Just open the toolbox from the menu (Procession Toolbox)

Comment: @Curlew Thank you for replying. In that case, I do have SEXTANTE installed and it seems that I can run nviz from there but I no results are shown.

Comment: On windows you need to have tcl and tk installed as well as grass and the nviz extension. Did you do all this stuff?

Comment: I have compiled/installed tcl/tk and GRASS. When I run nviz via the toobox in QGIS now, it processes the data which wasn't shown before but still no results when it reaches 100%.

Comment: Even i also tried to open and work with 3D functionality in nviz but there are no any result shown. previously i was using 2.2 but currently i am using QGIS 2.4 but isuue is history repeats again in 2.4 while running nviz from sextante. does anyone have the solution of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind...got it working by installing and **ONLY** installing **WinGRASS-6.4.1**.

Version 6.4.3 does not load, not for me anyway. Can finally run nviz perfectly instead of wasting time installing Ruby, tlc/tk, Python and various drivers seperately.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the standalone installer worked for me (winGRASS 6.4 standalone installer)

http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/binary/mswindows/native/WinGRASS-6.4.4-1-Setup.exe