# NVIS module not found in QGis

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, nviz

When I try to use the nvis module in Grass, QGis, pops-up a warning window saying "Module nviz not found". how can I solve this issue and use the nviz?

Comment: Which QGIS and GRASS versions are you using (or trying to use)?

Comment: I am using QGis 2.2.0 Valmiera and the Grass plugin is version 0.1.

Comment: Have you downloaded the **Processing** plugin and ran any GRASS functions via the Processing Toolbox?

Comment: I just tried to use the processing toolbox but there is something wrong: the nviz does not recognize any raster files to use as elevation file even though I have the DEM/raster file opened in Qgis... it runs but it shows no result.

Comment: Sorry, now it detected the raster DEM (I reopened it), it ran, but it still shows nothing at the end... do I have to open any nvis created file which was stored anywhere or something like this?

Comment: Press: 'View output'

Answer (score 2):

I faced a very similar problem a while ago: [Unable to load 'nviz' through GRASS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83702/unable-to-load-nviz-through-grass)

For me, downloading/installing **WinGRASS-6.4.1** and running GRASS 6.4.1.exe seperately from QGIS worked. I was able to use nviz (after configuring the project location and mapsets etc).

I still can't run it through QGIS for some reason but seems to work perfectly if I run it on its own.